# Question on A Walk Through Combinatorics, Chapter 3, Problem 21

Tags: combinatorics

In the solution to the following problem (A Walk Through Combinatorics - Chapter 3, problem 21):

> A round robin chess tournament had 2n participants from two countries, n from each country. There were no two players with the same number of points at the end. Prove that there was at least one player who scored at least as many points against his compatriots as against the players of the other country. (In chess, a player gets one point for a win and one half of a point for a draw.)

It is stated that if, $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ are the points scored by each player of one country, say A, in matches played against their own countrymen, and $b_1, b_2, ... b_n$ are the points accumulated by them in matches played against players from the other country, say B, then $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i \leq n^2/2$, since players from country A score at most half of all the points available in the international games. I understand why the total number of points available is $n^2$, but not why country A can score a maximum of half of the available points. Could someone please explain why this is so? Here is the complete solution to the problem:

> Let A be the country whose players scored, in totality, at most as many points in the international games as players from the other country. Take the $n$ players from A, and let $a_1, a_2, ···, a_n$ denote the number of points they accumulated against their countrymen. Let $b_1, b_2, ···, b_n$ be the number of points they accumulated against players from country B. Now assume that our claim is false, that is, $a_i < b_i$ for all i. In other words, $a_i ≤ b_i − 0.5$ for all i. Summing these inequalities over all $i ∈ [n]$, we get that
> $\sum_{i=1}^na_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^nb_i -n/2$ (3.4). On the other hand, note that $\sum_{i=1}^na_i = n(n-1)/2$ as any two players from A played each other once, and in each of those
> games, one point was up for grabs. Comparing this with (3.4), we get $n^2/2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^nb_i$ (3.5). Similarly, $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i \leq n^2/2$ (3.6) *as players from A got at most half of all points that were available at the international games.* Comparing (3.5) and (3.6) we see that $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i = n^2/2$ must hold. That is, $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i$ is exactly n/2 larger than $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$. Therefore, equality holds in (3.4), and so equality must hold in all equations of the type $a_i ≤ b_i − 0.5$. (Recall that (3.4) was obtained by taking the sum of these equations for all i.) Therefore, for all i, we must have $a_i = b_i − 0.5$, meaning that the total score of the ith player from country A was $a_i + b_i = 2a + 0.5$, which is never an integer. Therefore, no player from country A has a final score that is an integer. By the very same argument, no player from country B has a final score that is an integer. Indeed, in totality, players from B scored $n^2/2$ points against players from A, so the same argument works. This is a contradiction as we know there are no two players with the same final score. The number of possible non-integer final scores is less than 2n: indeed, they are 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, … (2n − 1) − 0.5, which is only 2n − 1 different scores for the 2n players. So there must be a player who did better
> against his compatriots than against players from the other country. ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let A be the country whose players scored, in totality, at most as many points in the international games as players from the other country.

In precise terms, this means $\sum_i b_i \leq n^2/2$ by assumption.  It's not that a given country can only score half the points against another one; rather, it's that we can't have both score more than half.  Since at least one country satisfies $\sum_ib_i \leq n^2/2$, choose one that satisfies that inequality and label that country "A".

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. We want to Prove that $a_i \le b_i$ for some $i$ , which implies $\Sigma \le \Sigma$. This answer is wrongly using $\Sigma \le \Sigma$ [[which is not yet Proved]] to imply $a_i \le b_i$ for some $i$ , which is circular logic.

Comment: @Prem I'll be candid with you: the only way I can interpret your comment as a criticism is if you're misinterpreting $a_i$ and $b_i$ as the scores for both countries' players rather than a decomposition of the $i$th player's score from country A.  You should re-read the problem again (in particular note that the $a_i$ has nothing to do with either the actual question or my answer)

Comment: Oh! I can't believe I missed that. Thank you for the answer.